# WITH statement followed by SET in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm pipelining a few SQL statements together and finding that I am having trouble following on from a WITH statement and using the results to the then go on and SET a variable. The error I'm getting is:

```
Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got keyword SET at [17:2]
```

The statements look like

```
WITH newtable AS (SELECT session, var FROM `table` WHERE session...)
(SET myvariable = (SELECT count(*) FROM newtable WHERE ....);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `WITH` following a `SELECT` statement as per this GCP Documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#sql_syntax

Given that limitation, you can just use DDL statement to create a table from a result of a query and set the variable.

```
create table newtable AS (SELECT session, var FROM table);
```

```
DECLARE myvariable NUMERIC;
SET myvariable = (SELECT count(*) FROM newtable);
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this but now I cannot seem to create a table, not sure if permissions of something else. Getting the following error: Invalid value: Table name "newtable" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request. at [7:1]

Comment: @disruptive, what worked for me is I included my project and the dataset ex. <PROJ>.<DATASET>.newtable:
create table <PROJ>.<DATASET>.newtable AS (SELECT session, var FROM table);

Comment: @disruptive, however for future if you have another question aside from the one you originally posted, please create another SO question so that other people from the community can easily find answers if they also encountered the same thing